# Ruby and public_method_defined? : strange behaviour

Tags: ruby

Whilst reading through the book "The well grounded Rubyist", I came across some strange behaviour. The idea behind the code is using one's own method_missing method. The only thing I am not able to grasp is, why this code gets executed, as I do not have any Person.all_with_* class methods defined, which in turn means that the self.public_method_defined?(attr) returns true (attr is friends and then hobbies).

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby1.9

class Person
        PEOPLE = []
        attr_reader :name, :hobbies, :friends

        def initialize(mame)
                @name = name
                @hobbies = []
                @friends = []
                PEOPLE << self
        end

        def has_hobby(hobby)
                @hobbies << hobby
        end

        def has_friend(friend)
                @friends << friend
        end

        def self.method_missing(m,*args)
                method = m.to_s
                if method.start_with?("all_with_")
                        attr = method[9..-1]
                        if self.public_method_defined?(attr)
                                PEOPLE.find_all do |person|
                                        person.send(attr).include?(args[0])
                                end
                        else
                                raise ArgumentError, "Can't find #{attr}"
                        end
                else
                        super
                end
        end
end

j = Person.new("John") 
p = Person.new("Paul") 
g = Person.new("George") 
r = Person.new("Ringo")

j.has_friend(p) 
j.has_friend(g) 
g.has_friend(p) 
r.has_hobby("rings")

Person.all_with_friends(p).each do |person| 
        puts "#{person.name} is friends with #{p.name}"
end 

Person.all_with_hobbies("rings").each do |person|
        puts "#{person.name} is into rings"
end
```

The output is

```
is friends with 
 is friends with 
 is into rings
```

which is really understandable, as there is nothing to be executed.

---

hmm, is is because I have accessors for friends and hobbies? But I thought they would only be accessed in instances, and not on the class-object level.

Comment: By the way, in your method missing, you might consider: `if method =~ /^all_with_(.*)$/` and then ` attr = $1`

Comment: Thank you, I love coding "efficient", that is less code of course. I am learning Ruby, so bare with me until I know how the regex engine works ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming that the code pasted into your question is the *exact* code that you're running then the problem is a typing mistake in `initialize`:

`def initialize(`**mame**`)` should be `def initialize(`**name**`)`

If the name of the parameter `name` is mistyped then this causes the line `@name = name`, rather than meaning

"set `@name` to the value of the parameter"

to mean

"set `@name` to the value returned by the method `name` (your attr reader)" (which of course is `nil` because it hasn't been set)

Hence all your Beatles get left without their names being set and the output is the 2 friends for Paul and Ringo's hobby but with all the names blank.

Comment: AAAHHHHH :D that is what you get, when working in vi for 2 days. I am so sorry for even putting this one up. Have to take this one back as RTFC in terms of code checking. Thank you.